# Convert Dict to Array{Tuple} in Julia

Tags: arrays, dictionary, julia

In Julia programming language, what is the best way to get an Array of Tuples from a Dict? I want the first element to be the key and the second element to be the value.
I have the following, but I don't know whether or not this is the best approach in Julia.

```
a = [(k,v) for (k,v) in d]
```

where `d` is a Dict.

By the way, if I do

```
a = [t for t in d]
```

I get an Array of  `k=>v` objects. For example, if I ask `typeof(3=>'3')` I get `Tuple{Int64,Char}`, but it is not printed as `(3,'3')`. What is exactly the difference between `k=>v` and  `(k,v)`? Is it just syntax sugar?

Comment: This seems like a good approach to me!

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderMorley. I tried your first approach, and it works fine. if you are unsatisfied, then perhaps you could clarify the output that you would like to see...?

Comment: I'm new to Julia (coming from python) and I'm still not familiar with some subtleties of the language. I mean, I prefer a not-elegant approach that will use generators instead of creating temporary arrays, as happens sometimes with Python if you do it the naive way (I'm working with really huge Dicts).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `collect(d)`, which again gives an array of `Pair`s of the form `k=>v`.

These can be indexed just as if it were a tuple:

```
julia> p = 3=>4
3=>4

julia> p[1]
3

julia> p[2]
4

julia> a, b = p
3=>4

julia> a
3

julia> b
4
```

so it effectively behaves like a tuple with two entries. 
However, it cannot be used when a `Tuple` is required.

Comment: This seems elegant and fast, since it uses the build-in function.

Answer (score 0):

For quick reference, here are a few ways:

```
# make a dictionary
julia> d = Dict(:a => 0, :b => 1)
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 2 entries:
  :a => 0
  :b => 1

# get the values
julia> collect(values(d))
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 0
 1

# get the keys
julia> collect(keys(d))
2-element Vector{Symbol}:
 :a
 :b

# make a named tuple from the key,value pairs
julia> (;d...)
(a = 0, b = 1)

# make a tuple of the values, dropping the keys
julia> (collect(values(d))...,)
(0, 1)
```

If keys are strings, special care is needed. See [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-make-a-named-tuple-from-a-dictionary/10899/35) for examples.